# Reference book for graph automorphism

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory

I have started learning graph theory. Can someone tell me some good books on graph automorphism ?

I have an average background in group theory and linear algebra.

Comment: Check out *Godsil, C.*, **Algebraic Graph Theory**, Springer, 2001.

Answer (score 2):

I can recommend to you Algebraic Graph Theory from Chris Godsil and Gordon Royle. It is from 2001. This book was my introduction to graph theory. It includes exercises, notes, and references. I think it is the perfect book if you have already a basic understanding of linear algebra and group theory. So I think it is right for your background.

Answer (score 1):

I think this reference script will help you to understand the fundamentals of graph automorphism. It covers all theories and has good explanation about all theory knowledge.
You can see it http://www.maths.qmul.ac.uk/~leonard/designtheory.org/library/preprints/auts.pdf